# Reading a List of tuples of str, bool from json into a class

Tags: python, json

I am trying to create a class that can be use to serialize and deserialize JSON. One of the elements that I need to represent is a list of pairs where the first is a string and the second is a boolean. The class should read/write the following JSON snippet:

```
{
  "ID": 1234,
  "Name": "Healthy",
  "Salad": {
    "Orange": false,
    "Apple": true,
    "Mango": true,
    "Banana": false
  }
}
```

So far the code that I got for this is:

```
import json
from typing import List


class Menu(object):

    def __init__(self, id: int, name: str, options: List[(str, bool)]):
        self.Name = name
        self.ID = id
        self.Metrics = options


def main():
    input_file = open("menus.json")
    json_dict = json.load(input_file)
    menus = Menu(**json_dict)
    print(str(menus))
    print(json.dumps(menus.__dict__, indent=4))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The error I get when I tried to read the list is:
(<class 'TypeError'>, TypeError('Too many parameters for typing.List; actual 2, expected 1'), <traceback object at 0x102f75740>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `typing.Dict`

**Ex:**

```
from typing import Dict
import json

data = {
  "ID": 1234,
  "Name": "Healthy",
  "Salad": {
    "Orange": False,
    "Apple": True,
    "Mango": True,
    "Banana": False
  }
}

class Menu(object):

    def __init__(self, ID: int, Name: str, Salad: Dict[(str, bool)]):
        self.Name = Name
        self.ID = ID
        self.Metrics = Salad

menus = Menu(**data)  # Updated args to match the input dict
print(json.dumps(menus.__dict__, indent=4))
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "Name": "Healthy",
    "ID": 1234,
    "Metrics": {
        "Orange": false,
        "Apple": true,
        "Mango": true,
        "Banana": false
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please also show how to create a Menu for example: salad = Dict[("Mango", True), ("Banana", False), ("Apple", True)]
    menu2 = Menu(3567, "Test", salad)